# How can I get the autentication token using rest parameters?

Tags: rest, automationanywhere

I trie to use Alias API in Automation Anywhere, but I dont know how can I get the token.

[image: REST Configuration]

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly are you trying to do? I can give you an example of a simple token Authuentication that is Bearer Token. It must set as a HEADER to your REST request like this. Header Authentication:"Bearer <actual token>. You can check more about how to implement it in your programming language on google.

Answer (score 1):

All of the APIs on Automation Anywhere are preceded by an Authentication API. The third-party application user first has to authenticate in order to use the downstream APIs.  Here are the details on how to get the authentication token:  https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/control-room/control-room-api/api-authentication.html.

If you have other questions, you can get answers on our [Product Documentation portal](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/).  You can also post questions to my developer evangelist group at Automation Anywhere at www.automationanywhere.com/developercommunity.